# What is the difference between a legend and a caption?

Tags: american-english, british-english

I have a graph with boxes of different colours and there is a part that explains what the coloured boxes mean.

Is this my graph caption or its legend? Are those words synonyms or used in a particular context?

Comment: http://lcweb2.loc.gov/ammem/ndlpedit/handbook/illus.html

Comment: What did the dictionary say?

Comment: @Drew, well, _this_ is the dictionary. I'm grateful for Mick's answer & deadrat's comment. People get here by asking questions to Google, and tend to find great answers here, so SX becomes more and more of a primary source, in a positive feedback loop. Dunno where the equilibrium between maximum utility and affordable SX resources is, but if embracing "basic" questions would actually be feasible, we should adapt and increase the scope, rather than trying to blow back the wind, and allocate moderator resources for actually doing a _disservice_ to visitors.

Comment: @Sz.: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term *legend* is used to describe information in charts, for example, to identify time series.

The term *caption* is used to identify or describe an entire chart or some other graphical content or table.

Both terms are, effectively, titles.

Comment: A legend is not a title. It's an instruction for interpreting pictorial representations like maps, charts, graphs, etc. A legend is usually more than text. A caption is text, and it can be a title, but it's really words to give context to some element. This element is usually pictorial (*Solvay Conference 1927*) and the caption usually applies to the entire element although it may draw attention to a part (*Einstein; front row, fifth from the right.*) In legal documents, the caption is the heading giving the parties, court, docket number, etc. In pictures and video, the caption can be dialog

Comment: The downvote is mine. Sorry, I meant to click to expand the vote total and missed.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the clarification. If you want to edit the answer, feel free.

Answer (score 2):

A legend provides a mapping that tells you what are being represented by the symbols in a graphic, usually a chart.

A caption is some text *accompanying* a graphic, for example a chart. It is not part of the graphic. It just provides some textual description of the graphic.

Answer (score 2):

"Captions" are titles. They are usually placed below illustrations. They are never complete sentences (except that when the caption and the legend run together, the caption ends with a full stop).

"Legends" are explanations and can take one or more sentences.

Here are the examples:

> Caption: Mars Bridge in 1909
>
> Legend: This photograph depicts the topography of Mainland as it looked like in 1909.

Comment: *Captions* can also be several sentences.  Both of your examples could be called captions. See [dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/caption?fallbackFrom=british-grammar).